# Python tar a directory and symmetric encrypt with gpg

Tags: python, tar, gnupg

At this point the script works great for a single file. When a directory is given it uses tar to create a singe file which works well, then the tar file is gpg encrypted with a password provided. The gpg works also. The problem is that when you decrypt the gpg file the tar is corrupted every time. I'm trying to find what I'm doing wrong here. Please help.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
# Takes file in does symmetric encryption with the password you provide
# then  adds it to a running IPFS(ipfs.io) instance.   
#
import os
import argparse
import gnupg
import ipfsapi
import tarfile

# Parse command arguments
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description='Encrypt file/directory and add it to IPFS')
parser.add_argument('-i','--input', help='File.txt or Directory', required=True)
parser.add_argument('-p','--password', help='Password to encrypt with', required=True)
args = parser.parse_args()

# Set GPG Home directory
gpg = gnupg.GPG(homedir='')
# Set GPG Encoding
gpg.encoding = 'utf-8'
# Get dataToEncrypt full path
dataToEncrypt = (os.path.abspath(args.input))
# Setup tar filename to end with .zip
tarFile = ("{}.tar".format(dataToEncrypt))
# Setup encrypted filename to end with .gpg
encryptedFile = ("{}.tar.gpg".format(dataToEncrypt))
# Tell module where IPFS instance is located
api = ipfsapi.connect('127.0.0.1', 5001)

def dataTar():
    if os.path.isfile(dataToEncrypt):
        return
else:
    #return
    with tarfile.open(tarFile, 'w|') as tar:
        tar.add(dataToEncrypt)
        tar.close()

def encryptFile():
    passphrase = (args.password)
    if os.path.isfile(dataToEncrypt):
        with open(dataToEncrypt, 'rb') as f:
            status = gpg.encrypt(f,
            encrypt=False,
            symmetric='AES256',
            passphrase=passphrase,
            armor=False,
            output=dataToEncrypt + ".gpg")

    else:
        with open(tarFile, 'rb') as f:
            status = gpg.encrypt(f,
            encrypt=False,
            symmetric='AES256',
            passphrase=passphrase,
            armor=False,
            output=dataToEncrypt + ".tar.gpg")
        print ('ok: ', status.ok)
        print ('status: ', status.status)
        print ('stderr: ', status.stderr)


def ipfsFile(encryptedFile):
    # Add encrypted file to IPFS
    ipfsLoadedFile = api.add(encryptedFile, wrap_with_directory=True)
    # Return Hash of new IPFS File
    fullHash = (ipfsLoadedFile[1])
    ipfsHash = fullHash['Hash']
    return(ipfsHash)

def delEncryptedFile(encryptedFile):
    try:
        os.remove(encryptedFile)
    except:
        print("Error: %s unable to find or delete file." % encryptedFile)


def main():
    dataTar()
    encryptFile()
    #ipfsFile(encryptedFile)
    #print ("File encrypted and added to IPFS with this hash " + ipfsFile(encryptedFile))
    #delEncryptedFile(encryptedFile)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Comment: How are you decrypting and un-tarring?

Comment: I'm just doing the following: gpg -d archive.tar.gpg | tar xz

Comment: Ok. Do `gpg -d archive.tar.gpg | tar xvf -`. `z` is not needed. Also we need a trailing `-`. It is working for me. But the extraction is a bit weird?

Comment: Just got this:tar: Damaged tar archive
tar: Retrying...
tar: Damaged tar archive
tar: Retrying...

Answer (score 0):

Code looks fine. I just tried it with https://pypi.org/project/python-gnupg/ and it works fine. I had to fix the API's according to this package, but I don't think that matters. Just diff it to see the changes. I don't see any problem except that you should be using `gpg -d file.tar.pgp | tar xvf -`.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
# Takes file in does symmetric encryption with the password you provide then
# adds it to a running IPFS (ipfs.io) instance.

import os
import argparse
import gnupg
import tarfile

parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(
    description='Encrypt file/directory and add it to IPFS')
parser.add_argument('-i','--input',
                    help='File.txt or Directory',
                    required=True)
parser.add_argument('-p','--password',
                    help='Password to encrypt with',
                    required=True)
args = parser.parse_args()

gpg = gnupg.GPG()
gpg.encoding = 'utf-8'
dataToEncrypt = (os.path.abspath(args.input))
tarFile = ("{}.tar".format(dataToEncrypt))
encryptedFile = ("{}.tar.gpg".format(dataToEncrypt))


def dataTar():
    if os.path.isfile(dataToEncrypt):
        return
    else:
        with tarfile.open(tarFile, 'w|') as tar:
            tar.add(dataToEncrypt)
            tar.close()

def encryptFile():
    passphrase = (args.password)
    if os.path.isfile(dataToEncrypt):
        with open(dataToEncrypt, 'rb') as f:
            status = gpg.encrypt(f.read(),
            recipients=None,
            symmetric='AES256',
            passphrase=passphrase,
            armor=False,
            output=dataToEncrypt + ".gpg")

    else:
        with open(tarFile, 'rb') as f:
            status = gpg.encrypt(f.read(),
            recipients=None,
            symmetric='AES256',
            passphrase=passphrase,
            armor=False,
            output=dataToEncrypt + ".tar.gpg")
        print ('ok: ', status.ok)
        print ('status: ', status.status)
        print ('stderr: ', status.stderr)


def ipfsFile(encryptedFile):
    ipfsLoadedFile = api.add(encryptedFile, wrap_with_directory=True)
    fullHash = (ipfsLoadedFile[1])
    ipfsHash = fullHash['Hash']
    return(ipfsHash)

def delEncryptedFile(encryptedFile):
    try:
        os.remove(encryptedFile)
    except:
        print("Error: %s unable to find or delete file." % encryptedFile)


def main():
    dataTar()
    encryptFile()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Comment: The code works great but, when you decrypt the gpg file are the contents damaged?

Comment: Nah it works fine for me. `gpg -d file.tar.pgp | tar xvf -` is the exact command I use.

Comment: Well, if the code is good and the gpg | tar decrypt is working for you I have no idea on how I'm getting errors. **tar: Damaged tar archive** any suggestions?

Comment: How do you encrypt the file? `--input <dir>`?

Comment: yes. Take input --input ~/testing/dir.to.backup -p password

Comment: That is strange. I would say do all the `gpg` steps from the command line and then try to see which step is going wrong. Btw, which python `gpg` are you using? I am using Vinay Sajips.

Comment: I'm just using **pip3 install python-gnupg**